# Refreshing site with parameters doesn't work in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I try to refresh the site when the url have a parameter I get a blank page.

My routes.js file is as follows :

```
const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="registration/:id" component={hideIfLoggedIn(Registration)}/>
    <Route path="registration" component={hideIfLoggedIn(Registration)}/>
    <Route path="reset-password" component={PasswordReset} />
    <Route path="portal" component={requireAuth(UserPage)} />
  </Route>
);
```

When I'm on http://localhost:8001/registration everything works perfect. If I refresh the page it works without problems.

But the problem is when I'm on http://localhost:8001/registration/step-one . First time when it loads it works good, but when I try to refresh the site I get a blank page.

**EDIT**

```
gulp.task('connect', ['watch'], function () {
    connect.server({
        root: ['dist'],
        port: config.port,
        base: config.devBaseUrl,
        livereload: true,
        fallback: 'dist/index.html'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your server to serve `index` html for any other route .
Browser request `/registration/step-one` , it does not found `index.html` at this path hence fails

Use connect-history-api-fallback.

The middleware is available through NPM and can easily be added.

`npm install --save connect-history-api-fallback`.
Import the library

`var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');`

Now you only need to add the middleware to your application like so

`var connect = require('connect');`

`var app = connect()
  .use(history())
  .listen(3000);`

Of course you can also use this piece of middleware with express:

`var express = require('express');`

`var app = express();`

`app.use(history());`

Comment: I'm using gulp and in gulp connect task I have `fallback: 'dist/index.html'`. I updated my question.